# MAUI: The issue with loading tabs from the Carousel page in the App

Tags: maui

I have the MAUI App, which has five tabs. The Home page is a Carousel page, and the tabs are ContentView pages. We log into the app, and then the five tabs appear. From the Carousel page, I am sending  WeakReferenceMessenger for each tab to swipe each tab from the home page.
Below is the Sample code for sending the WeakReferenceMessenger:

```
<CarouselView 
 x:Name="carouselView"
 CurrentItemChanged="OnCurrentItemChanged"
 Loop="False">
    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
            <control:Tab1Page/>
            <control:Tab2Page/>
            <control:Tab3Page/>
        </x:Array>
    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>

void OnCurrentItemChanged(object sender, CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Position:>>" + carouselView.Position);
    int index = carouselView.Position;
    AddWeakReferenceMessenger(index);
}

private void AddWeakReferenceMessenger(int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new HomeTabChangeMessage("Tab1"));
    }
    else if (index == 1)
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new HomeTabChangeMessage("Tab2"));
    }
    else if (index == 2)
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new HomeTabChangeMessage("Tab3"));
    }
}
```

This WeakReferenceMessenger is register to each tab.
Below is the sample code for one tab to subscribe to the message.

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<HomeTabChangeMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    if (m.Value == "Tab1")
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("isTab1Loaded:>>" + Utility.isTab1Loaded);
        if (!Utility.isTab1Loaded)
        {
            Utility.isTab1Loaded = true;
            //Implementing the features//
        }
    }
});
```

On each tab, we are setting bool values for loading the listview on the ContentView page. When the value is false, the data shows; when it is true, it does not.

Below is the code for setting the bool value:

```
public class Utility
{
    public static bool isTab1Loaded = false;
    public static bool isTab2Loaded = false;
    public static bool isTab3Loaded = false;
    public static bool isTab4Loaded = false;
    public static bool isTab5Loaded = false;
}
```

We log into the app, and then the five tabs appear. I logged out of the app and logged back in. Here, I am facing an issue: After logging into the app from the Home page, I tried to swipe to the tabs, but the five tabs data is not loading. At the same time again, I tried to swipe the tabs from the Home page, and the tabs data was loading. That means when I log out and log into the app and initially try to swipe tabs, the tab's data is not loading.

I am using WeakReferenceMessenger on the project, so this is sent multiple times. Is there any need to unregister it?

I created a demo project based on this issue, but the issue was not replicating on this demo project. For reference, I upload [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ckVbkSCp4NMFiYGtEuUwg1PBAFxIYMKb/view?usp=sharing)

Based on the code, I can't find any issue. Please provide me with a solution to resolve this issue.

**Update:**

I have created a screen recorder video and upload it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cGIkQN3YNlSu6x5lyZTyG0IEo9AWyv2_/view?usp=sharing) for the easy understanding.

My problem is, all the home tabs data are loading initially but it is not loading when I logged out from the app and logged in again.

I am using `WeakReferenceMessenger` for updating the data on each tabs. Sending `WeakReferenceMessenger` from the CarouselView when change the tab and subscribe it on each child pages to update the UI. (The codes are added on top)

I am also using a boolean variable to check the tab is already loaded or not. The initial value of the variable is false and after loading the tab I set the value as true. So If I go back to the tab again, the API calls will not initiated.

When I logging out and logging in I am resetting the value of all the boolean variable to false. But When I view the tabs the data is not loading.

I printed the value of boolean variable when I logging out and logging in and it is showing false initially and true after that. That means the `WeakReferenceMessenger` invoking multiple times. I suspect the issue is due to the `WeakReferenceMessenger's` multiple invoking; because of that the code execution is not going inside of the if block of the bool value check.

I tried to reproduce the issue on the demo project, but unfortunately on demo it is working fine.

Comment: What about the ViewModel of each Tab? How do you bind the ListView on each tab?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT There is no viewmodels I am using for each tab, data is binding from xaml.cs page itself. I have edited the question with more details, could you please have a look.

Comment: Everytime you swipe, the OnCurrentItemChanged will be invoked, and you may check if the lambda expression used to update the UI would be invoked? When you log out and log in again, the lambda expression should be executed, right?

Comment: When I log out and log in again, the events are firing but the boolean value is not getting true. I reset it to false, but I am getting false first and then true. Check this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI7KV.png

Comment: You mean the event fired twice when you swipe the tab? But I didn't see that in your demo.

Comment: So everytime you log out and log in, do you create a new Home page?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Yes the event is firing twice. In the demo also the same is happening. Did you check the screenshot i added on the last comment. It is the debugger line of the boolean value. First it showing false and then true. I can't reproduce the exact issue on the demo project. But I am facing this weird issue as I mentioned on the screen recorded video.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your video. I also run your demo project and cannot reproduce. I think that may because when you login again, the event may register twice. Then it will execute twice. So why not try creating a new instance each time you login in?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT For which one I need to create a new instance, is it for the utility class?

Comment: When you log in again, have you created a new instance of the page?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Not created any new instance. For which page I need to create a new instance?

Comment: I think it's HomePage.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Can you show me a demo code?

Comment: Maybe just set ```Application.Current.MainPage = new HomePage();``` when you login in?

Comment: Finally I fixed it by adding the WeakReferenceMessenger.Unregister code after register. WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<HomeTabChangeMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
 if (m.Value == "Tab1")
 {
  if (!Utility.isTab1Loaded)
  {
   Utility.isTab1Loaded = true;
   Debug.WriteLine("***Tab1Loaded***");
  }
 }
 WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Unregister<HomeTabChangeMessage>(this);
});

Comment: Could you please post it as your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. I agree with you that it may due to the multi-registration of messenger and you did a great job using Messenger Unregistration! I think it might be better if we could unregister all the messenger each time a user log out. I post an asnwer below hoping to help others with similar issues. Really thanks for your sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your sharing @Matthew Pans!

To those who have similar questions, it may due to the multiple registration of messenger. That's the reason why the event will be fired twice.

The solution posted by @Matthew Pans is to unregister the messenger after registering. Here is the relevant code,

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<HomeTabChangeMessage>(this, (r, m) => 
    { 
        if (m.Value == "Tab1") 
        { 
             if (!Utility.isTab1Loaded) 
             { 
                 Utility.isTab1Loaded = true; 
                 Debug.WriteLine("Tab1Loaded"); 
             } 
        } 
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Unregister<HomeTabChangeMessage>(this); 
    });
```

For more info, please refer to [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger).